Dividing $m$ pizzas among $n$ students
I'm working on problem 4.1.14 from the book Graph Theory by Bondy and Murty. I'd appreciate a solution or hint for part 2.
Problem Statement:
$m$ identical pizzas are to be shared equally amongst $n$ students.

Show how this goal can be achieved by dividing the pizzas into a total of $m+n
-d$ pieces, where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.
By considering a suitable bipartite graph, show that no division into a smaller number of pieces will achieve the same objective.

My Work:

Assume the area of each pizza is $n$ and represent each pizza by a segment of length $n$. A division of a pizza corresponds to dividing its segment of length $n$. Now, we can take of all of the pizzas and concatenate their segments to form one of length $nm$. In order to divide the pizzas equally, we cut this long segment at integer multiples of $m$. Moreover the segment is already cut at multiples of $n$ (corresponding to the initial $m$ pizzas). The number of final pieces is given by the number of cuts (including the cut at position $nm$). In total the number of cuts is $\frac{nm}{n} + \frac{nm}{m} - \frac{nm}{lcm(m,n)} = m+n - d$.

I imagine the bipartite graph $G$ we should consider has $m$ vertices on one side and $n$ vertices on the other, corresponding to pizzas and students, respectively. We connect a pizza vertex to a student vertex if the student gets a non-zero share of the pizza. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of ideas on how to continue. The problem appears in the introductory chapter about trees, so I'd assume the proof has something to do with them, but I have no clue.



Perhaps this can get you started:
Let's stick with the graph $G$ you were considering. Each edge actually represents a slice and connects the pizza it came from to the student it's going to (note that since we are trying to minimise the number of slices, we would never have a student receiving more than one slice from the same pizza, so this truly is a graph).
And so $E(G) \equiv $
number of slices.
If this graph were connected, we would have $E(G) \ge m + n - 1$
Suppose instead that the graph can be decomposed into $x$ disjoint connected subgraphs. Then we have that $E(G) \ge m + n - x$
So you're left trying to show that $x \le d$.
EDIT: for the benefit of future readers, to finish the argument, consider the ratio of students to pizzas within each subgraph.

Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I think I'm still missing something. Considering the graph $G$ with $m = 2$ and $n = 3$, I should prove that it can only have one connected component. I know that every vertex should have degree $\geq 1$, but it is easy to construct a $G$ with $2$ components satisfying this condition, i.e. the edges are $(1,1), (2,2), (2,3)$. I know this $G$ does not correspond to a valid division of the pizzas, but I don't really know what extra conditions I have to impose to get rid of such configurations.

Ok so you have subgraph based on (2,2) and (2,3). As you say, this isn't valid but can you determine why it isn't valid?
Suppose you have some disjoint connected subgraph. Think about the ratio of pizzas to students within that subgraph. It still needs to be m:n.

Yes!!! thank you, I think got it now. The idea is that every connected component is itself a pizza-student graph, so it should have the same ratio. Letting $m = dx, n = dy$ with $x, y$ coprime, there's a connected component having $< x$ vertices from the pizza side if we assume $> d$ connected components. The issue is that the subgraph corresponding to that component cannot have a ratio of $\frac{x}{y}$.
